# Adding one to binary number in C?

Tags: c, binary

I have a 9  bit binary string say "111110000" how would I go about adding 1 to this binary number.

I DO NOT mean concatenation (ie after adding 1 the string should be "111110001").

This should work for any 9 bit binary string.

This code is part of a 2's compliment converter.

I have been at this for quite a while and am completely lost. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean to say that you have a character representation of a binary number, and you wish to perform arithmetic on that number without converting the representation to internal binary, but instead operating on the character representation?  Look up "full adder" as an electronic circuit design.

Comment: Ugh. Don't implement your own full adder. For 9 bits, just convert it to `int` and back.

Comment: Assuming Hot Licks got the question right, you scan from right to left, flipping bits, until the bit you just flipped becomes a '1'. Try it with a pencil and paper to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation according to what rici said in the comment :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 9
char const flip[] = "10"; // flip[0]='1' flip[1]='0'

main()
{

   char str[SIZE+1] = "111110100"; // as in your example
   str[SIZE] = '\0';   
   printf("number to add '1' : %s\n", str);

   int index = SIZE-1;

   while(index >= 0)  // bit by bit from right to left
   {
       str[index] = flip[str[index] -'0']; //flip bit

       if(str[index] == '1') // if bit flips to '1' addition is done
       {
           printf("result: %s\n", str);
           return 0;
       }

       if(index ==0 ) // processed all bits still didn't finish ==> ?
       {
           printf("overflow!! \n");
           return 0;
       }
       index--;
   }


}
```

**UPDATE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 9
char const flip[] = "10";
int main()
{
   int index = SIZE;
   char in[SIZE+1] = "111110100", out[SIZE+2] = "0";
   strcat(out, in);
   while(index >= 0)
   {
       out[index] = flip[out[index] -'0'];
       if(out[index] == '1') break;
       index--;
   }
   printf("result %s\n", out);
}
```

Comment: should be `char str[SIZE+1]`

Comment: Why @BLUEPIXY ? I need a string of 9 chars not 10

Comment: `printf("result: %s\n", str);` does not work correctly. Because it is necessary to have ended in NUL character.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I get it, see EDIT, is it ok ?

Comment: `str[SIZE] = '\0';`  is not required, but it becomes insurance when there is an initialization used in long strings.

Comment: This is wrong. The result should be 10 bits. And the output should not overwrite the input. In any case, one might as well write a full adder and still use less lines of code.

Comment: @david.pfx I don't agree too much with the word `WRONG`! yet if you want a 10bits result this code doesn't require much change. Concerning your complain about how long is the code I recommend you read again the question and see that it is not a requirement, anyway the same method can be written in less lines if you insist

Comment: @chouaib: I call it wrong because (a) it doesn't produce the right answer for the given data and (b) it can't easily be modified to do so. The technique you've used is quite unsuitable for incorporation into a converter, as requested. And you left `int` off `main`. Please take these as helpful hints to allow you to improve your answer.

Comment: @david.pfx (a)Not WRONG since the unique `wrong` result is specified as "overflow". (b) see the UPDATE. Now I'm curious to see your better shorter suitable way of solving this question as it is

Comment: Improved, but (a) shouldn't index start at SIZE+1 (b) isn't `if(index==0)` unnecessary? And why do you need an `in` array rather than just a string, and if you need it why give it a size? And OP did ask for a 9 bit version, not a 4 bit version. Sorry to be picky!

Comment: @david.pfx Thanks for the remarks, they helped improving the code ;) edit done

Comment: I hope the OP is getting value for money. +1 for persistence!

Comment: He didn't show since he asks the question!! I don't know but i would be very curious to see what others reacted to my question